# Rails code block in controller for repeated code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

In my Rails application I am using the [odf-report gem](https://github.com/sandrods/odf-report) to generate reports. However I have an `if condition` in my method with the same 110 lines of code in each clause with one or two changes at the end. I am wondering if there is a way to define the 110 lines that are being repeated in a code block and just call that code block in my main method? Below is a sample of the method:

```
def print_enrolment_form_completed
  kid = Kid.find(params[:id])
  if kid.not_anaphylactic?
    report = ODFReport::Report.new("#{Rails.root}/app/reports/Student_Enrolment_Completed.odt") do |r|
       #same 110 lines of code 
    end
  else
    report = ODFReport::Report.new("#{Rails.root}/app/reports/Student_Enrolment_Completed_Allergy.odt") do |r|
       #same 110 lines of code 
       r.add_field(:a2, kid.fish ? "Yes" : "No" )
       r.add_field(:a3, kid.eggs ? "Yes" : "No" )
       r.add_field(:a4, kid.milk ? "Yes" : "No" )
    end
  end
end
```

My goal is to just yield a code block where the comment is listed above and have the 110 lines defined elsewhere in the controller. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Can't you just set which report you are using with the if. And then move the 110 lines outside of the if?  Just make sure that report is in scope by doing report =nil outside the if.

Comment: your if statement makes no sense - in both branches you create same report

Comment: You can extract the code into a Proc and execute the code in two separate context using `instance_eval` method

Comment: @Doon turns out your idea was the path I was looking for, it got the job done. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely agree that that many lines of code in the controller is code smell and not just for the lack of DRYness.

That said, you might not be in a place where you can do the full refactoring now.  The only difference between the two branches is the string passed to the new and three lines at the end.

```
  report = ODFReport::Report.new(kid.not_anaphylactic? ? "#{Rails.root}/app/reports/Student_Enrolment_Completed.odt" : "#{Rails.root}/app/reports/Student_Enrolment_Completed_Allergy.odt") do |r|
   #same 110 lines of code
    If kid.not_anaphylactic?
      r.add_field(:a2, kid.fish ? "Yes" : "No" )
      r.add_field(:a3, kid.eggs ? "Yes" : "No" )
      r.add_field(:a4, kid.milk ? "Yes" : "No" )
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong, if you have 1000s of lines on controller action.
I think you should consider delayed jobs / active jobs or sidekiq or resque

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a method containing that 110 lines of code and use it in the if statement?

```
    def method_name(z, y)
      puts z + y
    end

    x = 4

    if x > 3 
      method_name(6, 7)
    else
      method_name(1, 4)
    end
```